# Laravel 5 Routing Issue - Bad Method Call Exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm attempting to simply send a 'PUT' request to one of my routes (which is called as a resource in the route file), yet I recieve this traceback as the response.

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 273: Method [show] does not exist.

    in Controller.php line 273
    at Controller->__call('show', array('1'))
    at AccountControllerV2->show('1')
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(AccountControllerV2), 'show'), array('account' => '1')) in Controller.php line 246
    at Controller->callAction('show', array('account' => '1')) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 162
    at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(AccountControllerV2), object(Route), 'show') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 107
    at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 108
    at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(AccountControllerV2), object(Route), object(Request), 'show') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 67
    at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\API\V2\AccountControllerV2', 'show') in Route.php line 198
    at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 131
    at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 692
    at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 47
    at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 694
    at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 661
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 619
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in HttpsProtocol.php line 15
    at HttpsProtocol->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening.

Here is a code snippet from the Controller itself (which extends BaseController):

```
/**
     * Update the currently logged User in storage.
     *
     * @return Response 201
     * @return jsonArray account
     * @return string message
     */

    public function update($account_id) {
        $input = Input::all();
        $message = 'Account Successfully Updated';
        $user = Auth::User();
```

And here is the Route declaration:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v2', 'namespace' => 'API\V2', 'middleware' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::resource('challenges', 'ChallengeControllerV2', ['only'=> ['index','store','update','destroy']]);
    Route::resource('groups', 'GroupControllerV2');
    Route::resource('account', 'AccountControllerV2');
```

The call is being made to the correct path.  Any ideas why I'm getting what seems to be an illogical response?  There is no additional middleware/filters attached to the controller than what is shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that in Laravel 5 if you do not specify the resources available on a Route it will assume that they are all there (unlike in Laravel 4 where it checks to see what resources are available in all controllers).  So I had to change the line like so.

```
Route::resource('account', 'AccountControllerV2', ['only'=> ['index','update','destroy']]);
```